# Each (funcion) is not working when combined with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product with multiple color variation.

What I am trying to do is to only show the photos of the selected color on thumbnail. For example, for the same chair, there are blue, black, red and green color variations. When the red one is selected, the other photos of other colors will disappear in the thumbnail.

I made it working the desktop version using css, however, on the mobile version, I have not had any luck with the slider, I think I should try to match the selected color with the color attribute, and remove the `data-slick-index` attribute of the unselected ones so they will not appear on the thumbnail, but I am not sure why my codes are giving me errors.

```
$(funcion() {
  $('li.product-single__thumbnails-item').each(function(){
    var $mobilemodelselected = document.getElementById("FeaturedImage-product-template");
    var $mobilemodelcolor = $mobilemodelselected.getAttribute("color-option");
    var $mobilecolorcheck = $(this).attr('color-option');

    if ($mobilemodelcolor != $mobilecolorcheck) { 
     $('li.product-single__thumbnails-item').removeAttribute('data-slick-index');
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: `funcion` - bad start - check the developer tools console for any errors

Comment: `$('li.product-single__thumbnails-item').removeAttribute('data-slick-index');` this will remove that attribute from ALL elements that match `li.product-single__thumbnails-item` - is that what you want? - perhaps you wanted `$(this)` here as well?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you so much for helping and pointing out my stupid mistake, I have added your comment and it seems like the data-slick-index have not been deleted after implementing the code. I got the following  from the console too: 
theme.js?1423537320336464041:2897 Uncaught TypeError: 
$(...).removeAttribute is not a function
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (theme.js)
    at Function.each (vendor.js)
    at re.fn.init.each (vendor.js)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (theme.js)
    at u (vendor.js)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (vendor.js)
    at ready (vendor.js)